# PHP: unable to decode base64 encoded JPEG

Tags: php, base64

I'm trying to render a base64 encoded image with PHP. You can find the image raw data here: https://justpaste.it/base64_image. The script I'm currently using is:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$data="data:image/jpeg;base64,9/j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD...."; 
list($mime,$data64)=explode(",",$data);
$img=imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($data64));
imagejpeg($img);
```

but the image doesn't display at all due to some error:

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

What am I missing?

Comment: First thing I'd be doing is confirming the `$data64` variable contained the full string (by length). Then try dumping the base-64 decoded string out to a file and see if it's a valid JPG

Comment: Hi Phil, I do confirm that $data64 is the full string, and I also tried to dump everything on a file and it doesn't work. However if I upload the non-working JPG file to one online service to repair corrupted images I can see the image I'm looking for. I guess it might be a problem with encoding the string.

Comment: _" I also tried to dump everything on a file and it doesn't work"_ <- well there's your problem

Comment: yes but then I can recover the image itself when I upload the file to one of these services

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way out rebuilding the 3 initial hex chars of the file as follow:

```
$data64=base64_decode($data64);
$data64[0]="\xFF";
$data64[1]="\xD8";
$data64[2]="\xFF";
$data64=base64_encode($data64);
```